# FullCalendar links open a new tab, don't want that

Tags: javascript

I have D7 with FullCalendar (7.x-2.0) installed. When viewing a month view and clicking on an event, the event opens in a whole new browser tab (no matter what browser I'm using).

I don't want that, I want to stay in the same tab.  I read at http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/ that I could change the "self" value from False to True.  See below,I did that in fullcalendar.fullcalendar.js and now the link opens itself in the existing tab AND a new tab both.

How do I get this to work the way I want?   Thank in advance for any help you can give me.

```
var options = {
  eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    if (settings.sameWindow) {
      window.open(calEvent.url, '_self');
    }
    else {
      window.open(calEvent.url);
    }
    return false;
```

Answer (score 1):

In view edit, click on FullCalendar settings under Layout. There is an option to open events in new window.

[image: FullCalendar Settings]

Comment: That was just the ticket.  THank you very much!!!!